# How to get only href value from link using AMP script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have one URL field coming from salesforce and i need only href instead of complete URL using amp script.

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/?hl=en-GB&authuser=1' target='_blank'>Test</a>
```

i need only href value in one var to solve my issue.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression in Ampscript. This will isolate the link from within the *a* tag in your ampscript variable. You can then use the link within RedirectTo function, allowing you to have it tracked:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @text = "<a href=""https://salesforce.stackexchange.com""target=""_blank"">Salesforce</a>"
SET @matching = '<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["''])(.*?)\1'
SET @link = RegExMatch(@text, @matching, 2)
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank">Salesforce Stack Exchange</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working.

Comment: but while we tried preview and test automatically extra url adding j&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Duplicate+Join&utm_term=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%%&utm_id=24232&sfmc_id=23816084&campid=

Comment: Could you please help me